# Facebook php sdk-v4~5.0@dev could not find user is logged in or not

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using laravel framework just installed facebook php sdk "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "~5.0@dev" via composer. Now initially when i try to find whether user is logged in or not, didn't get userid eventhough i logged in already.

In the examples i searched they are using $user_id = $fb->getUser(); to get userID, but i couldn't use that method(got this error: Call to undefined method Facebook\Facebook::getUser()), so i used $user_id = $fb->getClient();

I'm trying this in my localhost, so in facebook have created an app and mentioned as 'localhost' in the app domain.Also gave site url as my localhost url.

My code is,

```
            session_start();
            require_once( 'vendor/autoload.php' );
            $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
              'app_id'                => '---',
              'app_secret'            => '****',
              'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
              'cookie'                => 'true'
            ]);
            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            $user_id = $fb->getClient();

           if($user_id){
                    try {
                          $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
                    } catch( Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e ) {
                          echo $e->getMessage();
                          exit;
                    }
           }
           else{
                    $permissions = ['email', 'publish_actions', 'user_posts']; // optional
                    $callback    = 'http://localhost:8000/add-customer/Renters';
                    $loginUrl    = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);
                    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
           }
```

Also i couldn't use methods like getUser(),api('/me'),getSessionFromRedirect()..

when i try to feed a post on facebook only from the app account(in which i have created the app) i can post, if i login from some other account and run the code to feed a post in wall, then it's throwing an error like "Graph returned an error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".

What I want is to determine from any account user is logged in or not and getting access token if logged in and able to post on user wall.
Please help me to proceed further..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use extended permission with other users than your app's admins/testers/developers, your app has to be reviewed by facebook. It's all in the docs though:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference

Comment: Okey i will try it out

Comment: I'm really sorry for my late reply @Tobi, your post was helpful, thank  you!